# Debugging a frozen Android application

Tags: java, android, debugging

I have an Android app with three threads, the main thread and two worker threads.  The threads need to communicate with each other regularly.

I had originally gone about doing this in a horrible way that everyone here would yell at me for.  I saved instances of the thread in each thread and called methods of the class from the other threads if a thread needed that functionality.  It worked, but I knew it wasn't right.

Since that was wrong, I went back through and changed each instance of a thread to an instance of the thread's handler, and each thread function call I replaced with a handler.sendMessage call.

Now the program doesn't work. It just freezes, and I have no idea whats going on.  When using the debug perspective, I step through the main thread but all I get is the function

```
boolean hasMessages(Handler h, int what, Object object)
{
...
}
```

from the MessageQueue.  The other threads are looping in their run() function which doesn't do anything exciting.  None of my logs are printing.  I am at a loss for what is happening and I don't know what steps I should take next to continue debugging it.  All I changed was adding handlers and sending messages.  Can you guys suggest any next steps I should take for debugging?

Edit: Here is some code, I'm having no luck

Main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    connectionStatusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connectionStatus);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    commandView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.commandView);
    focusView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.focusView);
    mApplication = ((myApplication) this.getApplication());

    ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mHandler, mApplication);
    VoiceRecognitionThread voiceThread = new VoiceRecognitionThread(mApplication, this);

    connectedThread.setHandlers(mHandler, voiceThread.getHandler());
    voiceThread.setHandlers(mHandler, connectedThread.getHandler());

    connectedThread.start();
    voiceThread.start();
}
```

ConnectedThread and VoiceRecognitionThread both extend HandlerThread. They both create a class level Handler which handles messages sent to those threads.  getHandler returns a reference to those handlers.

Comment: Do you have a backup?

Comment: @MatiCicero I do have a backup, but since the code is against convention I'd rather solve this problem and not run back to the working but not correct version

Comment: @323go I do have code, but its pretty massive and I'd rather not post it here.  I'm more looking for some help with the debugging process rather than an answer to my problem.

Comment: Check your code into your version control and then reduce it as much as possible to get to the basics. Most likely, you'll find your problem right there. If not, you can then post it. Other than that... lot's of `Log.d`s, and don't forget breakpoints.

Comment: In the end it turned out to be a typo I found with a breakpoint.  I still don't understand why it made my UI thread hang though, but I'll take it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) and feed it with messages via its handler object:

```
HandlerThread thread1 = new HandlerThread("Thread Name");
thread1.start();
handler1 = new MyHandler(thread1.getLooper());

// pass message for thread 1
handler1.sendmessage()

// and same for threads 2 and 3
```

Note that if you plan your threads to be long running, a far better
solution would be to use an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).

IntentService are services and, as such, are by far less susceptible to 
Android reclamation then resources gets low.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gilad, I shied away from using Service or IntentService because they seem to work on the principle of the main thread gives them work, they do the work, and return the answer.  For my application, I need one thread polling a bluetooth buffer and the other listening for voice commands and executing actions when voice commands are given.  They don't get any work requests from the UI thread besides start